# How to make a new table in MYSQL

Tags: android, mysql, database, android-edittext

I want to write a code that gets a name in an Edittext by user and makes a new table in the MYSQL database useing that name.

For example I enter "hello" in the Edittext and my app makes a table with the name of "hello" in the mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on how to create tables here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-create-tables.htm

After you read that, you need to execute a query: `"CREATE TABLE " + tableName` and additional settings for the table.

Answer (score 0):

To create a table at run time or at user defined level you need to pass the Parameter ie the table name to the Java/PHP code .

Java used JDBC API to connect with Database and perform DB level operations which can be execution of DDL/DML scripts.
Ref below link to see hot use JDBC API and how to create user defined table at run time

https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-statement-example-create-a-table/